# Automapper unexpected behaviour with map between inherited types

Tags: c#, oop, automapper

I have the following situation (C#):

```
public class A: B
{
      public ComplexType MyCT {get;set;}

}

public class B: 
{
      public string MyString {get;set;}

}
```

I have an instance of A and I want to use Automapper to map it to an instance of B as after the mapping I do not need "MyCT" (this is a cut down version obviously).

```
B myB = Mapper.Map<A, B>(myA);
```

but when I try to do something with myB (I'm saving it into Azure which can't handle my complex type, hence trying to throw it away if you like) an exception is thrown telling my that MyCT is still hanging around the myB object.

When I debug I can cast it to A and sure enough I have access to MyCT.

What am missing, I feel like I'm fundamentally missing something here presumably to do with the inheritance between the two types.

Comment: What does the Mapper.CreateMap() expression look like? My bet is you don't have one.

Comment: thanks all! Needless to say you were both correct. I did have the CreateMaps (I've used Automapper lots of times before) but the method I was calling it in was not being called. It was late in the day, and I thought my call to Map would have thrown some kind of "Automapper not set up" exception - oh well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have not defined a mapping for the two types which is simply:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>();
```

*(If you take a look at the [Getting Started](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started) guide it gives some hints on how you can centralize these mapping configurations in one place on application startup.)*

It looks like that without the mapping between the two types having been defined, Automapper is falling back to an upcast of your `A` instance to the `B` type. You actually want to achieve a [flattening](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Flattening) which Automapper can only do if it knows about the mapping between the two types explicitly.

Here's a code sample that illustrates this:

```
using System;
using AutoMapper;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B b = Mapper.Map<A, B>(new A());
        Console.WriteLine(b.GetType()); //A

        Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>();       //define the mapping
        b = Mapper.Map<A, B>(new A());
        Console.WriteLine(b.GetType()); //B

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class A: B
{
}

public class B
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>()`.